# validate file uploaded by ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to validate a file uploaded by **AJAX** in **laravel**, this is my code in my controller :

```
public function changePicture(Request $request)
{
     // get file : 
     $file = $request->file('image');

     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:2048'
     ]);

     if ($validator->fails())
          return response()->json(['is' => 'failed', 'error' => $validator->getMessageBag()]);

     return response()->json(['is'=>'success']);
}
```

but nothing happens when upload an incorrect file, but when upload a valid file, get the second response :

> is:success .

my **js** code :

```
 $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/profile/change-picture',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response){
                if(response.is === 'failed'){
                        $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
                }
            }
        });
```

but after waiting there is a error :

> POST Content-Length of 20315736 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes.

any idea !! **thanks**

Comment: if u use **ajax** , u must first check with **javascript** ,because verification by **PHP**  will be after uploading the entire image.

Comment: Have you set `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in Ajax calling?

Comment: If it's not failing maybe your image isn't actually wrong?  What are you sending?

Comment: @Nourein that is irrelevant as ALL validation should ultimately be done on the back end, always.

Comment: @OP - please add `required` to the image validator rules

Comment: @Gufran Hasan i have placed the **Ajax** code

Comment: What file are you sending to test? Maybe you're sending a correct file. Are you sending a PDF, maybe a `.docx` file, perhaps a `.md`. What are you sending?

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the HTML form doesn't include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: but after waiting there is a error : 
>  POST Content-Length of 20315736 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes.

Comment: @Christopher Francisco *.rar > 15Mb !

Answer (score 2):

Add these props to your ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
```

Also, make sure your file is appended to the form data. There are plenty of ways to do that, here's one:

```
var data = new FormData();

jQuery.each(jQuery('#image')[0].files, function(index, file) {
    data.append('my-image-' + index, file);
});
```

#### About the error

Your webserver or PHP probably has a max upload file size. I suggest testing with a file lower than that value.

Answer (score 0):

8388608 bytes is 8M, the default limit in PHP. Update your post_max_size in php.ini to a larger value.

upload_max_filesize sets the max file size that a user can upload while  post_max_size sets the maximum amount of data that can be sent via a POST in a form.

So you can set upload_max_filesize to 1 meg, which will mean that the biggest single file a user can upload is 1 megabyte, but they could upload 5 of them at once if the post_max_size was set to 5.